# Вывод данных из бд по категории [закрыто]

Tags: php, база-данных, вывод, статьи

Необходимо вывести карточки из игроков нужного состава. Как на примере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот пример кода
Из бд

```
 function get_category()
    {
    $players =$GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT * FROM `players` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`category_id` = `players`.`category_id` ORDER BY `players`.`category_id`");
    return $players;
    }
```

Страница вывода

```
<?php

$players=get_category();

?>

<?php
foreach ($players as $player) : ?>

<?php if ($player['category_name'] != $last_category): ?>
<?php if (!$first) : echo "</div></div>"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="structure">
<div class="structure_logo">
<h1></h1>
</div>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

<?php endif; $last_category =$player['category_name'] ;?>

<a href="">
<div class="player">
<div class="player_head"><img src="<?php echo $player["image"]; ?>" alt=""></div>
<div class="player_info">
<div class="player_name">
<p><span class="player_number"><?php echo $player["number"]; ?> </span><?php echo $player["name"]; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<?php $first = false; endforeach; ?>
```

Структуры таблиц

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/abYVs.jpg

Сама бд 
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Время создания: Авг 27 2020 г., 14:36
-- Версия сервера: 10.3.22-MariaDB
-- Версия PHP: 7.1.33

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- База данных: `test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `categories`
--

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'VAn'),
(3, 'dada'),
(4, 'Мелкиий'),
(6, 'simple');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `players`
--

CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `newid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `number` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `info` text NOT NULL,
  `image` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `players`
--

INSERT INTO `players` (`newid`, `player_id`, `name`, `number`, `info`, `image`, `category_id`) VALUES
(4, 231, 'sadsda', 10, 'вмп', '', 3),
(5, 222, 'Billy Herrington', 69, 'цукцукцукцукцукуц', 'https://pinger.kz/storage/avatars/escjxndwkaiklc1-5e941b93e1591.jpeg', 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------


--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `categories`
--
ALTER TABLE `categories`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Индексы таблицы `players`
--
ALTER TABLE `players`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`newid`);

--
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `categories`
--
ALTER TABLE `categories`
  MODIFY `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `players`
--
ALTER TABLE `players`
  MODIFY `newid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

--

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа сохраненных таблиц
--

--
-- Ограничения внешнего ключа таблицы `players`
--
ALTER TABLE `players`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `players_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Выводится либо пустой массив, либо все игроки в одной карусели.

Answer (score 1):

Не правильно делаешь INNER JOIN а точнее не по тому полю
`categories`.`category_id` напиши `categories`.`id`

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Ставлю класс)))

Comment: Потому что у тебя в двух таблицах одинаковые имена вот и выводиться только Имя игроков, для этого тебя надо в запросе перечислить все поля что тебе надо (ставить * , это плохая практика )  и сделать такое дать алиас categories.name AS categories_name

Comment: Кстати, отметь этот вопрос, что он решен )